# Type 'String._CharacterView.Index' (aka 'String.Index') does not conform to protocol 'FixedWidthInteger'

Tags: swift

I´ve managed to fix a bunch of errors, but I cannot get this function to work.

```
// Substring
func substring(_ start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
    return self.substring(with: NSRange(self.characters.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: start) ..< self.characters.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: end)))
    // error here "Type 'String._CharacterView.Index' (aka 'String.Index') does not conform to protocol 'FixedWidthInteger'"
}
```

Comment: What class/extension is this method in?

Comment: Sorry for the late response .I already fix the problem for this one but I Have another question I amm stack with for almost a week . I was going to send you my codes to see whats wrong . I don't know how to send you privately on stackoverflow. Can you help ?